# Construct a short exact sequence that is not split

Tags: modules, exact-sequence

I am currently studying about exact sequence. To illustrate that not all short exact sequences are split, my teacher provided an example in the homework.

For every $m \geqslant2$ construct a short exact sequence of abelian groups

$$0\rightarrow \mathbb{Z}_m \rightarrow \mathbb{Z}_{m^2}\rightarrow \mathbb{Z}_m\rightarrow 0.$$

At first I tried the following:

Define the homomorphism from $\mathbb{Z} _2$  to $\mathbb{Z}_{m^2}$ as identity map $id_{\mathbb{Z}_m}$. The homomorphism $\pi$ from $\mathbb{Z}_{m^2}$ to $\mathbb{Z}_2$  as following:

$$\pi(\bar{n})=\bar{0} , 0\leqslant n\leqslant m-1,\pi(\bar{n})=n\quad  mod\quad m, m\leqslant n\leqslant m^2-1.$$

Then we have $Im(id_{\mathbb{Z_m}})=Ker(\pi)$. But I quickly realized $\pi$ is **NOT** a group homomorphism.

Can anyone give me some hints?  Any idea will be appreciated!  Thanks in advance!

Comment: Welcome to mse! Have you tried to do this in the special case $m=2$? In that case you want to build a short exact sequence 

$$0 \to \mathbb{Z}/2 \overset{i}{\to} \mathbb{Z}/4 \overset{\pi}{\to} \mathbb{Z}/2 \to 0.$$ 

Can you find maps $i$ and $\pi$ in this special case? After all, $\mathbb{Z}/4$ doesn't have too many subgroups isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}/2$, so there's only a few choices of $i$ to try.

Comment: Thank you,  I'll try now

Comment: Keep in mind that your "identity" map is not a homomorphism as well (I presume you are defining $\mathbb Z_m$ to be $\{0,\cdots,m-1\}$ as a set, otherwise the identity would not even be well defined into $\mathbb Z_{m^2}$.)